# PHP - remove HTML tags from string except <img>

Tags: php, html

I want to remove all tags except the *img* tag,

```
$words = strip_tags($words, '<img>');
```

Is it useful?

Comment: strip_tags($words, '<img>'); Take a look at the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php).

Comment: What answers exactly do you except? "Yes" or "No" or more? The usefulness depends on the context and that's completely missing in your question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, to remove tags.
But `strip_tags()` won't help against the most dangerous thing - an [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). You will need some regular expression, or use http://htmlpurifier.org/ to be sure there are no unwanted parameters in the `<img>` tag.

Comment: ooops, hehe funny typo :) good tag, let's leave it as is :)

Comment: I think this is the first useful typo I have ever seen. +1 for being thorough with unintentional humor. The <ponies /> will ride.